# Problem with Mysql and using the function last insert ID

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, railo

When I run my query I get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select last_insert_id() as productid' at line 3
>
> NativeErrorCode   number  1064

queryError  string  :

```
insert into products (systemname, systemversion, created_date) 
values ('web andrea', '', now()); select last_insert_id() as productid;
```

DatabaseName    string  MySQL

DatabaseVersion string  5.6.10-log

DriverName  string  MySQL-AB JDBC Driver

```
insert into products (systemname, systemversion, created_date) values ('web andrea', '', now()); select last_insert_id() as productid;
```

I expected the data to get inserted but it fails here.

Thanks in advance

Andrea

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @GMB's comment, the reason it errors is because multiple statements are NOT allowed by default for security reasons - to protect against sql injection. They can be enabled by [adding `allowMultiQueries=true` to the DSN settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299326/coldfusion-multiple-sql-statements-in-a-query). However, be sure ALL queries use cfqueryparam to protect against sql injection.

Having said that, you don't need either `last_insert_id()` or multiple statements. Instead, use [cfquery's "result" attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html). After the insert, CF populates the variable `yourResultName.GENERATEDKEY` with the new record id

```
<cfquery result="yourResultName" datasource="yourDSN">
   insert into products (systemname, systemversion, created_date) 
   values (
      <cfqueryparam value="web andrea" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      , <cfqueryparam value="" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      , now()
   )
</cfquery>

<!--- DEMO --->
<cfoutput>
   New ID (yourResultName.GENERATEDKEY) = #yourResultName.GENERATEDKEY#
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not running *one* query but *two queries* : an `INSERT`, then a `SELECT`.

From your application, you would need to make *two* distinct query calls (one for the insert, the other to get the last inserted id).

Please note that it is likely that your database driver has a built-in function to return the last inserted id (equivalent for [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.insert-id.php) in PHP).

Comment: It should also be noted that you wouldn't necessarily _want_ to run back-to-back queries. By the time you `SELECT` the last inserted `id`, another session could have `INSERT`ed a new `id`, and that would be the one your `SELECT` picks up. You want to get the `id` that you `INSERT`ed during the same query session that you did the `INSERT`.